# Is there a LL(*) parser that is not generated

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I need to change the grammar rules of my parser at runtime and I would like to avoid regenerating the parser each time the rules changes.

Is there a parser that do not use code generation?

Regards,

Comment: Why is LL* relevant to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use (meaning probably implement yourself, not likely to be a library lying around) an [Earley parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser).

You will of course pay an overhead price for this. If your grammar and the source it parses are small, this is likely to be fine.

Otherwise you might reconsider; why is it that you don't want to rebuild the parser?  Most parser generators run far faster than people can edit rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) (either hand-written or something like [boost:spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/))

PEGs are not a strict superset of LL grammars, but are generally more expressive, as they have various extra features such as limited negation and following context testing.